# How to find JCDIWebListener class for IBM WebSphere Application Server version 9.0.0.10?

Tags: annotations, websphere, java-ee-8

I try to start the Enterprise Application in WebSphere Application Server version 9.0.0.10 and there is missing class `com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIWebListener`.

Fix pack for version 9.0.0.10 didn't help for this. There still are warning that prevents application starting in SystemLog.log file:

```
000000a7 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIWebListener
```

Where to get that class if latest fix pack won't bring that?

Or is there other libraries where to get that class? I'm running on Java version = `1.8.0_191`, Java Runtime Version = `8.0.5.26`

Comment: JCDIWebListener does not exist in WebSphere 9. It's a WebSphere extension of the Apache OpenWebBeans implementation, which was used for CDI in <=8.5.5, but the CDI implementation was wholly replaced in 9.0, and Apache OpenWebBeans (and, consequently, your missing class) is no longer included in the product.

Comment: Ok, but can I use AppServer/lib/ext folder in WAS9 to store these libraries (which include that JCDIWebListener) like I did for openwebbeans-web-2.0.8.jar? It solved my earlier missing class problem. But I guess then I have to take that from WAS8.5.5 fix pack..otherwise we are in trouble with our applications that should run in WAS9.

Comment: If it works, that's great, but I can't imagine it would be supported. What exactly is your app doing with these CDI classes? The package implies that that is an internal class, not an API (they usually use "com.ibm.websphere" for those, so I'm curious why your app needs it in the first place.